# table mysql custom order

Tags: php, mysql

i have a mysql table with some columns, id_piatto, descrizione_piatto, prezzo_piatto, categoria_piatto and other,

i have a query "order by categoria_piatto asc" but this query isn't good for me,

i would a query order custom, so when fetch array run show me first result categoria_piatto=antipasti second result categoria_piatto=primi piatti third result categoria_piatto=secondo etc...

How can i do? with group by clause or other?

```
$portate = mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT * 
  FROM tablo_piatti 
 where id_ristorante = '$idrist' 
   and categoria_piatto = '$cat_piatto'  
   and disponibilita = 'Si' 
 order 
    by categoria_piatto asc 
");
        while($riga = mysqli_fetch_array($portate))
```

Comment: You could change the order of the categories so that the id of the category also became the sort order.  This means that if you add new types, you don't have to rewrite your SQL each time.  Or add a sort order to the category table again allowing you to dynamically change things (but may need an extra join).

Comment: Note that you're open to sql injection - and FIELD() would be the standard solution in this instance

Comment: For prevent sql injection  i use these $nomepiatto = ucfirst(addslashes($_POST['nomepiatto'])); is it enough to prevent sql-injections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression.

```
...
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN categoria_piatto = 'antipasti' THEN
             1
           WHEN categoria_piatto = 'primi' THEN
             2
           WHEN categoria_piatto = 'secondo' THEN
             3
           ...
         END
...
```

And, as a side note, you should learn to use parameterised queries.